# Delay Program visual C#

Tags: c#

I have made a little bit of code. It simulates a delay. But the method Wait() can be async so a set async in it. But now there needs to be an instrunction inside the Wait(). How do i have to make a function like that. I thougt of something like `Func<int> func = new Func<int>(getWaitingTime);` But I'm am not sure and that alone is not enough.

```
public class speed
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public speed(int id)
  {
    this.Id = id;
  }

  public async void wait() //here is the problem
  {                          
    int waitingTime = getWaitingTime();
    Console.Writeline("string.Format("Done with {0}: {1} ms", this.Id, waitingTime));
  }

  private int getWaitingTime()
  {
     int waitingTime = new Random().Next(2000);
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(waitingTime);
     return waitingTime;
  }
}

for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
{
   speed slow = new speed(counter);
   slow.wait();
}
```

Comment: `async` doesn't make a function asynchronous, it allows you to *await* already asynchronous method calls. Why don't you use `Task.Delay()` anyway, eg `await Task.Delay(1000)`?

Comment: Also avoid `async void` methods unless you know that you need them. `async void` is only meant for event handlers or event-handler-like methods. Any other method should return a Task

Comment: _I'm am not sure and that alone is not enough_ Why are you **unsure**? Have you run your code, does it throw an exception? if so what? Does it appear to work? Does it only work sometimes? **In what way are you _unsure_?**

Comment: You already did your wait anyway in your getWaitingTime() where you Sleep(waitingTime);

Comment: Do you mean I should replace `getWaitingTime()` with someting like: `await Task.Factory.StartNew(func);`
And it was my intention to make a program that could be async to learn someting new. Maybe this program can be sync but when it is a real delay on an internetconnection it can be async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question currectly you may use something like :

```
  public async void wait() //here is the problem
  {                          
    int waitingTime = await getWaitingTime();
    Console.Writeline("string.Format("Done with {0}: {1} ms", this.Id, waitingTime));
  }

  private Task<int> getWaitingTime()
  {     
     return new Task<int>.Run(() =>
     {  
        int waitingTime = new Random().Next(2000);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(waitingTime);
        return waitingTime;
     });
  }
```

Or simply use `Task.Delay(time);` as suggested by Ron Beyer (this way you'll need only one method instead of two) :

```
    public async void wait()
    {
        int waitingTime = new Random().Next(2000);
        await Task.Delay(waitingTime);
        Console.WriteLine(waitingTime);
    }
```

Comment: Why not just make `getWaitingTime` async and `await Task.Delay(waitingTime)`?

Comment: Looks good. It now works and I have used this: `Func<int> func = new Func<int>(getWaitingTime);` with then `int waitingTime = await Task.Factory.StartNew(func);` and then the console.Write line.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thank you Ron, i just thought that OP wanted to keep his `getWaitingTime()` method as it is.

Comment: wait should really be returning a `Task`, you should never do async void unless you are writing a event handler.